# Neo4j - required hardware for big data

Tags: neo4j, bigdata, sizing

I would like to use Neo4j because it supports two key features of my requirements: fast `full-text-search` (based on Lucene engine in Neo4j) and `joins` (or relationships in graphs naming).

I went to [Neo4j hardware sizing calculator](https://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator) in order to estimate the hardware size needed for my service and got `Graph exceeds calculator limits`.

1. Can Neo4j handle my load? (see sizes below)
2. If so, what hardware should I use for it?
3. Are there alternatives which support the key features I need I should look up instead?

My expected data size:
Concurrent request per second: ~5000
Nodes: ~1,000,000,000
Relationships: ~5,000,000,000
Properties per node: ~30
Properties per relationship: ~10

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific requirements, but it seems that your graph is just too large for the calculator  (It is noted that  "for use cases with large graphs or high transaction volume, it's important to work with the Neo4j engineering team to get things right. For this reason, the calculator is currently limited to graphs of about 64GB in size and 4 cores"). Your graph is larger than 64GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator), as of neo4j 3.0 release there is no theoretical limit to the size of your graph. Previously there was a a 34 billion node limit.